# How to fix unwanted lines and dashes in LaTex tables?

Tags: tables, pdftex, overleaf

I am creating a LaTex table based on a paper https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/we.2510 (and compiling it in `Overleaf`). However, the output Table has some unwanted `----` symbols and lines appearing in the Second Row (image attached) [image: Output of the LaTex code for the table]. What is causing this and how I can fix it? `Overleaf` also shows a `\hbox too wide warning` (image attached) [image: Warning message in Overleaf -- and the unwanted dashes are visible in Row 2 of the Table].

This is the .tex script:-

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Summary of top-three optimisation parameters for the ANN\label{comparison_ann}}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Optimiser}   & \textbf{Learning Rate} &\textbf{Optimisation parameters} & \textbf{Accuracy} \\ \hline
\textbf{Adam}   & 0.001 & $\beta_{1}$ = 0.90, $\beta_{2}$ = 0.999           & \textbf{93.81\%}                            \\ \hline
RMSProp                                      & 0.001                            & $\rho$ = 0.90                                                                  & 92.64\%                            \\ \hline
Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)         & 0.01                                             & Momentum = 0 (Undamped)                                                                   & 78.36\%                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Any help and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The dashes do not appear when I typeset your code. You may have invisible characters in your source. Try typing again the contents of the problematic cells.Or copy/paste the table you posted back to your source and try again.

Comment: @Themis thanks for the suggestion! I copy pasted the code from here back into the source and it worked like a charm! It is very interesting that invisible characters can appear in .tex sources, something I didn't know before :-) Cheers and Thanks